# Designing a fixed layout table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to build a 3 fixed columns table, left and right columns should be 47px wide, middle column should use the remaining space.
Here is what I did:

HTML:

```
<table class='table poem'>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <span id="title">
            <h3 class='hide center'>Beautiful Poem</h3>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="verse">
    <td style='vertical-align: middle; text-align: right;'>
        <img src="{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/images/showPoem/Transparent.png') }}" alt="" height="33" width="47" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class='verse'>
            <div class='hide intro'>Here's the special poem for them.</div>
            <div class='hide intro'>Give to them just like a gem.</div>
            <div class='hide intro'>But if you like, I'll change verse.</div>
            <div class='hide intro'>Click an arrow, need not rehearse.</div>
            <div class='hide intro'>When it's ready, click the star. </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style='vertical-align: middle;'>
        <a href= {{ links.changeIntro }}>
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/images/showPoem/NextVerse.png') }}" alt="Next Intro" height="33" width="47" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
table.poem { table-layout: fixed; }
tr.verse { width: 100%; }
tr.verse > td:nth-child(1) { width: 47px; }
/*tr.verse > td:nth-child(2) { width: 70%; }*/
tr.verse > td:nth-child(3) { width: 47px; }
#title, #closing, #ps { min-height: 50px; width: 100%; }
div.verse
{
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Marronsuisse/YB9EG/) is a jsFiddle.

However, the table is divided in 3 columns of equal width..
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to obtain the desired effect (having the table and columns with correct fixed dimension on page load) by adding `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags in my table:

```
<table class='table poem'>
    <colgroup>
        <col width=47px>
        <col width=100%>
        <col width=47px>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="title">
                <h3 class='hide center'>{{ poem.poemTitle }}</h3>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="verse">
        <td>
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/images/showPoem/Transparent.png') }}" alt="" height="33" width="47" />                
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='verse'>
                <div class='hide intro'>{{ poem.introLine1 }}</div>
                <div class='hide intro'>{{ poem.introLine2 }}</div>
                <div class='hide intro'>{{ poem.introLine3 }}</div>
                <div class='hide intro'>{{ poem.introLine4 }}</div>
                <div class='hide intro'>{{ poem.introLine5 }}</div>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
           <a href= {{ links.changeIntro }}>
           <img src="{{ asset('bundles/yopyourownpoet/images/showPoem/NextVerse.png') }}" alt="Next Intro" height="33" width="47" />
           </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table.poem { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
tr.verse { width: 100%; }
tr.verse > td { vertical-align: middle; }
#title, #closing, #ps { min-height: 50px; width: 100%; }
#closing { padding-top: 25px; font-size: 120%; }
#ps { font-style: italic; font-size: 120%; }
div.verse
{
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use this

```
    <div style="width=100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"> 
        <div  style="width=40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;float:left;">
        </div>
        <div  style="width=40%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; float:right;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a very large table then `table-layout: fixed;` is a good idea, as the browser only needs to read the first row in order to compute and render the entire table, so it loads faster.

But if not, you can use the `table-layout` default value and set `width:100%;` to the table or any fixed width you need:

```
table.poem { 
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 100%; 
}
td{
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
tr.verse { width: 100%; }
tr.verse > td:nth-child(1) { width: 47px; }
tr.verse > td:nth-child(3) { width: 47px; }
#title, #closing, #ps { 
   min-height: 50px; 
   width: 100%; 
}
div.verse
{
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB9EG/2/)

#### Advices:

- You can do this without using tables, this is a simple 3 columns layout
- Avoid use selectors as `nth-child`, is nice but is not compatible with older browsers (eg: IE8)
- You can replace the bunch of `<div class='hide intro'>` for line breaks or use span instead

Comment: I like table-layout: fixed because my table directly shows with the correct dimensions directly on page load, I don't have the table growing when content is added. Thanks for the advices, could you explain why I should replace the divs?

Comment: @Marronsuisse: is more efficient, but semantically thinks why put each line of a verse within a layer? is just text and text should be inside `<p>`,`<span>`,...,

Comment: You're making a point, I'll try to clean my html and be more careful of semantics. Thanks @Tom.